# Android: How to create a ContextMenu for a custom View

Tags: android, menu, contextmenu

I'd like to show a ContextMenu for a custom View which is not part of an AdapterView.

I called

```
myActivity.registerForContextMenu(myView);
```

and the ContextMenu already shows up.

But I don't know how to access the data of myView in

```
@Override
onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) //...
```

I thought I could create a custom menuInfo in

```
@Override
onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) //...
```

This is from the docs: "menuInfo - Extra information about the item for which the context menu should be shown. This information will vary depending on the class of v."

Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your custom view class should override [`getContextMenuInfo()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContextMenuInfo%28%29) and return a custom object implementing [`ContextMenuInfo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo.html) (not very hard considering the interface has no members!) and which contains the extra per-view data you want the menu-click handler to get.

You can then get at this object from `onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)` by calling `item.getMenuInfo()` and casting the value returned.

Comment: I've got it working finally, I was using custom GridView in which `getContextMenuInfo()` method was not implemented. I've posted [here](http://vinaybhargav.wordpress.com/2014/07/20/android-floating-context-menu-for-listviewgridview/) in case if someone need a sample.